# jQuery animate scrollTop doesn't scroll on any browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im making a website, when the user clicks on a sort of button of the navbar the entire webpage should scroll to the section containing the information selected by the user.  But it just simply won’t work for some reason. It used to, but something broke.

navbar code:

```html
<ul id="outJS">
 <li>
   <a href="#section0"> Infomratica </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

The section code:

```html
<section id="section0" class="sezione0">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="text-align: center;">
        <div id="heading" class="row" style="margin-top: 125px;">
            <div class="col-md" style="margin-bottom: 80px;">Infomatica</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="button" id="button-3">
                <div id="circle"></div><a>Infomatica</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

The code that should provide the scroll capability is this:

```js
$('a[href*="#"]').on("click", function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        let target = $($(this).attr("href"));
        console.log(target.length);


        if (target.length) {
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
          }, 1000);
        }



      });
```

I've tried all the possibilities, and none of them worked.

Do you have any idea of what caused it, and how to fix it ?

EDIT:

I have imported jQuery

Answer (score 0):

It seems your opening anchor tag is missing the `>`. It should be:

```
<a href="#section0">Informatica</a>
```

Working example below:

```js
$('a[href*="#"]').on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let target = $($(this).attr("href"));
  if (target.length) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="outJS">
 <li>
   <a href="#section0">Informatica</a>
 </li>
</ul>

<section id="section0" class="sezione0">
  <div class="container-fluid" style="text-align: center;">
    <div id="heading" class="row" style="margin-top: 125px;">
      <div class="col-md" style="margin-bottom: 80px;">Informatica</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="button" id="button-3">
        <div id="circle"></div><a>Informatica</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Yeah sorry, I wrote the
wrong code, the tag is generated by javascripe via appendChild, so there are no errors in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the updated javascript for the scrolling effect.

You will unable to select element with **attr()** method. For this, you will need to use **$(this)**. Also, I have added the temporary UL style for demo. you can remove it while implementation.

```js
$('a[href*="#"]').on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let target = $(this);
    console.log(target.length);

    if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

```css
ul{
height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="outJS">
 <li>
   <a href="#section0"> Infomratica </a>
 </li>
</ul>

<section id="section0" class="sezione0">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="text-align: center;">
        <div id="heading" class="row" style="margin-top: 125px;">
            <div class="col-md" style="margin-bottom: 80px;">Infomatica</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="button" id="button-3">
                <div id="circle"></div><a>Infomatica</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```